# Jenkins GitHub Organization jobs triggered by schedule

Tags: jenkins, github-organizations, build-triggers

I've setup an Octopus organization with multiple repositories inside.

One of those repositories has automated tests. I'm trying to setup the Jenkinsfile in that repo to make the job trigger periodically instead of only on SCM change.
I haven't found documentation that shows this is possible. Even the job, after is automatically created shows the BUILD TRIGGER option but of course it can't be saved.

[Jenkins Organization Job Configuration Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nal2p.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the way of doing this by using the "properties" option. In this example, the job will trigger by changes pushed to GitHub and also on a periodic basis (every 60 minutes):

```
properties([pipelineTriggers([cron('H/60 * * * *'), [$class: 'GitHubPushTrigger']])])
```